# SQLAlchemy: Should I define relationship() directive in parent class or child class?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy documentation recommends that one should add `relationship()` directive to the parent table. By mistake, I added `relationship()` directive to the child class throughout my project. The problem is that the project was quite big and almost ready to be deployed. Although, it appears to be working fine at least for now. So far googling doesn't help me. Is that fine or Should I change it?

Comment: A `relationship` is usually *one*-to-*many*. So one *parent* refers to *multiple children*. So unless it is a *one-to-one* relationship, this probably can have some design problems. But if you added some parameters like `back_populates` this behavior is of course altered.

Comment: I have used `backref` instead of  `back_populates`.

Comment: Well given you modeled it as a many-to-one relation, I do not see much problems with it.